# Python Pandas multi-index values not moving over in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following Python Pandas dataframe:

[image]

import pandas as pd

I then run this code to format the table how I want:

```
col_mapping = {'Central Mixedwood (CM)': ['CM Area (ha)', 'CM % of LSA*'], 
               'Lower Boreal Highlands (LBH)': ['LBH Area (ha)','LBH % of LSA'], 
                'Total LSA': ['Total Area (ha)', 'Total Area % of LSA']}
cols = [(k,v) for k,sublist in col_mapping.items() 
              for v in sublist]
p_table.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
p_table
```

Which Yields:
[image]

The Labels are all in the correct spot however the values have not shifted to the correct column they remain the same as before, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-index the axis first:

```
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
>>> p_table = p_table.reindex_axis(idx.get_level_values(1), axis=1)
>>> p_table.columns = idx
```